# Cast session variable to bool

Tags: c#, asp.net, request

Why can't I do this?

```
if ((bool)Request["genericError"] != true)
   {
       return;
   }
```

Compiler gives me:

> Cannot convert type 'string' to 'bool'

`Request["genericError"]` should be an object, so why does the compiler think its a string?

I'm looking for the reason for this, not how to sidestep it (using `Convert`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What makes you think that `Request["genericError"]` should be an object?

Assuming `Request` is an [`HttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) (as I suspect), the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx) is of type string.

Comment: Apologies I mis-read the intellisense comment "returns HTTPRequest object"

Comment: @m.edmondson: So, John gave you a coherent answer, right? I don't see a tick.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment - You might find thats due to not being able to accept an answer yet. I don't see much reputation...

Comment: @m.edmondson: Apologies, seems I must have misconstrued my point, which was: You should mark the most satisfying response to your question as an answer. Granted, other answers may arise, but let's call a spade a spade, this answer is all you asked for.

Comment: Actually, if anything the answer is incorrect as he didn't ask about the indexer but rather about the value :)

Answer (score 3):

Because it is a string. Try:

```
if ( bool.parse (Request["genericError"] ) != true)  return;
```

Better yet,

use `bool.TryParse'   etc ...

Answer (score 1):

In .NET a NameValueCollection is defined as: 
Represents a collection of associated String keys and **String** values that can be accessed either with the key or with the index.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The value of the request variable is a string. It isn't a session object (that would be Session["genericError"]). Request variables are always strings IIRC.